Getting error message when trying to render in Quarto in RStudio
I am trying to render a Quarto file that uses both R and Python into a pdf but I keep getting this error message:
Error in rbind(info, getNamespaceInfo(env, "S3methods")) : 
  number of columns of matrices must match (see arg 2)
Calls: :: ... tryCatch -> tryCatchList -> tryCatchOne -> <Anonymous>
Execution halted

I have reviewed my code for formatting errors, have retyped my code to catch any mistakes, tried ChatGPT for solutions, etc. but am coming up empty.
ETA: The error message does not point to a specific code. The different chunks themselves do not produce any error messages. The error appears after I click the render button.
This is the error full message:
Error in rbind(info, getNamespaceInfo(env, "S3methods")) : 
  number of columns of matrices must match (see arg 2)
Calls: :: ... tryCatch -> tryCatchList -> tryCatchOne -> <Anonymous>
Execution halted
R installation:
  Version: 3.5.1
  Path: C:/Users/marie/anaconda3/envs/myenviro310/lib/R
  LibPaths:
    - C:/Users/marie/AppData/Local/R/win-library/4.4
    - C:/Users/marie/anaconda3/envs/myenviro310/Lib/R/library
  knitr: (None)
  rmarkdown: (None)

The knitr package is not available in this R installation.
Install with install.packages("knitr")

The rmarkdown package is not available in this R installation.
Install with install.packages("rmarkdown")

"I have both rmarkdown and knitr installed and loaded"
Pasting my session info as well:
R version 4.4.1 (2024-06-14 ucrt)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64
Running under: Windows 10 x64 (build 19045)

Matrix products: default


locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=English_United States.utf8  LC_CTYPE=English_United States.utf8   
[3] LC_MONETARY=English_United States.utf8 LC_NUMERIC=C                          
[5] LC_TIME=English_United States.utf8    

time zone: America/New_York
tzcode source: internal

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
 [1] reticulate_1.39.0 png_0.1-8         reshape2_1.4.4    lubridate_1.9.3   forcats_1.0.0    
 [6] stringr_1.5.1     dplyr_1.1.4       purrr_1.0.2       readr_2.1.5       tidyr_1.3.1      
[11] tibble_3.2.1      ggplot2_3.5.1     tidyverse_2.0.0  

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] Matrix_1.7-0      gtable_0.3.5      jsonlite_1.8.8    compiler_4.4.1    tidyselect_1.2.1 
 [6] Rcpp_1.0.13       scales_1.3.0      lattice_0.22-6    plyr_1.8.9        R6_2.5.1         
[11] labeling_0.4.3    generics_0.1.3    knitr_1.48        munsell_0.5.1     pillar_1.9.0     
[16] tzdb_0.4.0        rlang_1.1.4       utf8_1.2.4        stringi_1.8.4     xfun_0.47        
[21] timechange_0.3.0  cli_3.6.3         withr_3.0.1       magrittr_2.0.3    grid_4.4.1       
[26] rstudioapi_0.16.0 hms_1.1.3         lifecycle_1.0.4   vctrs_0.6.5       glue_1.7.0       
[31] farver_2.1.2      fansi_1.0.6       colorspace_2.1-1  tools_4.4.1       pkgconfig_2.0.3  


Hi! Could you share a minimal reproducible code example that gives you the error message? A minimal reproducible example makes it easier for us to think along.  See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example/5963610#5963610

What's with C:/Users/marie/anaconda3/envs/myenviro310 , are your managing your R installation though conda / Anaconda?  Whole installation, including packages?  I.e. are installing packages with install.packages() or with conda / Anaconda Navigator / any other conda interface?

@margusl I'm not managing R through Anaconda/conda, only my Python installation/packages. Should that path point to where R is installed?

You probably need to figure out why is this location picked up by quarto.  Start  by checking https://quarto.org/docs/troubleshooting/ & https://quarto.org/bug-reports.html  to get more information on what details you should include to help others help you. Like starting with quarto check output, it should be executed in the same / similar environment as your render job, i.e. from RStudio terminal.  With QUARTO_LOG_LEVEL=DEBUG env variable set you'd get more details on why it chose some specific paths.

For relevant sessionInfo()  /  sessioninfo::session_info()  output please make sure to execute those in the same environment where rendering fails, not in RStudio interactive session, i.e.  try to render this - https://quarto.org/docs/troubleshooting/#knitr - and also include reported environment variables to your question (may check first that they do not leak API secrets, personal  details etc)

Also include a content of minimal QMD document that still fails to render. Is one r chunk and one python chunk enough to make it fail? What if  that r chunk calls library(tidyverse) ? If you are pointing reticulate to a specific environment, (i.e. reticulate::use_condaenv("myenviro310") ), do include that in your minimal test qmd as well.
Note that https://github.com/quarto-dev/quarto-cli/discussions is also quite active, there might be more people who have debugged various quoarto + reticulate + conda issues.
